# Calling 2 functions using asp:linkButton

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, linkbutton

I need to call 2 functions in the onclick using the LinkButton control, it cannot execute the javascript Function :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnVirement" value="virement" runat="server" style="color: #f15d22;" onclick="CatchLinkVirement();btnVirement_Click" ><u><b>Comment effectuer un virement ?</b></u></asp:LinkButton>
```

and this is the CatchLinkVirement() javaScript function :

```
function CatchLinkVirement() {

    var pLinkVirement = document.getElementById("btnVirement").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("pClickVirement", pLinkVirement);
    alert(pLinkVirement);
}
```

and this is my codebehind :

```
public void btnVirement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["BonSavoirPopup"] = "BonAsavoirVirement";
        Response.Redirect("Mytransfers.aspx");


 }
```

Comment: use onclientclick  for javascript function and onclick for server side function

Comment: i tried but it doesn't execute the CatchlinkVirement() !

Comment: @anass90 see updated answer, add `return` in `OnClientClick`

Comment: worked!! you're the man !

Comment: @Div if i want to get a static value in the linkbutton how can i proceed? when i set a value in the linkbutton and then get it in the function by getelementbyid("btnvirement").value i get an error in the console telling that the value is null !

Comment: @anass90 Try like `var id = ('id=$btnVirement').val();`

Comment: @Div Uncaught TypeError: "id=$btnVirement".val is not a function!

Comment: @anass90 *get it in the function by getelementbyid("btnvirement").value* please, show your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122912/discussion-between-anass-90-and-div).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
OnClick="btnVirement_Click" OnClientClick="return CatchLinkVirement();"
```

Comment: it didnt worked ! what about onclick ? should i ignore it?

Comment: onclick is server side (asp) onclientclick is client side (js) - this should work - are you getting any errors in your js console?

Answer (score 1):

Write below line inside your button click handler(Server Side)

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "SimpleScript", "CatchLinkVirement();", true)
```

This way you can call javascript function from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnVirement" value="virement" runat="server" OnClick="btnVirement_Click" OnClientClick="return CatchLinkVirement();">Comment effectuer un virement ?</asp:LinkButton>
```

in above code hierarchy of function calling is,

1. `OnClientClick` JavaScript function ie.  **CatchLinkVirement**  called, then
2. `OnClick` server event(function) ie.  **btnVirement_Click** called

On single click on LinkButton both function called. `OnClientClick`   event was works only on server control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.If you want to call code behind from Javascript

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnVirement" value="virement" runat="server" style="color: #f15d22;" onclick="btnVirement_Click" OnClientClick="return CatchLinkVirement(); ><u><b>Comment effectuer un virement ?</b></u></asp:LinkButton>
```

JavaScript Function

```
   function CatchLinkVirement() {

        var pLinkVirement = document.getElementById("btnVirement").value;
        sessionStorage.setItem("pClickVirement", pLinkVirement);
        alert(pLinkVirement);
        document.getElementById('btnVirement').click();
    }
```

Code .aspx.cs

```
public void btnVirement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["BonSavoirPopup"] = "BonAsavoirVirement";
        Response.Redirect("Mytransfers.aspx");
 }
```